# Progressively load NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, scroll, nstableview

I have a view-based tableview that needs to have the following functionality:

1. Has some kind of view at the bottom that spinns when scrolled to
2. When scrolled to, the view turns into a spinner
3. When I am done with my operation, refresh the table view so that new content is added and the refresh view is moved to the bottom.
4. Keep scroll position after new content is added.

I understand that this can be done by using a view-based table view and having one of the cells at the bottom custom made using a case in my data source/delegate to start the request when it is moved to a superview. The question I'm asking is for some alternative ways to accomplish this. (And number 4 on my list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem my self by just creating a dummy NSTableCellView subclass with a dot in it (to symbolize that it will load progressively). When the `- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row` method is called (and I create the view) I execute my load function to add more items to the list.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to do a full view-based table view, you can rely on `tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:`.